# Thread Synchronization C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, pthreads

I am having this weird issue with threads. On my mac with OS X this works fine but once I more it over to my desktop that is running Ubuntu, I am facing issues.

Essentially what I am doing is the following:

```
Function() {

   for(i = 1 to 10)
      while(array not completely changed) {
         pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
         -- perform actions
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&unlock);
      }
   }
}
```

And I have two threads running this function. While it is supposed to be running in such a manner that is:

```
Thread 1 grabs lock
performs opperations on array
Thread 1 releases lock
Thread 2 grabs lock
performs calculations on array
Thread 2 releases lock
```

and so on in a back and forth pattern until the array have been completed changed but on Linux all of the calculations of Thread 1 complete and then Thread 2 starts.

So I will get:

```
Thread 1 grabs lock
performs opperations on array
Thread 1 releases lock
Thread 1 grabs lock
performs calculations on array
Thread 1 releases lock
Thread 1 grabs lock
performs calculations on array
Thread 1 releases lock
```

And so on until the array is completely changed, once I increment the for loop, then Thread 2 will perform all calculations and continue this pattern.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: It's the thread scheduler that you are interested of. Check this out http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html. Since version 3.14, Linux provides a deadline scheduling policy (SCHED_DEADLINE). You are probably interested in round-robin policy.

Comment: Note we have `std::thread` class in the current c++ standard, that should be used preferably over `pthreads` native library API.

Comment: If you want to force a switch to a specific thread you need to manage that yourself, otherwise it is completely random which thread will get the lock (its not the order they reach the lock).

Answer (score 4):

You're experiencing "starvation".  Add a small `nanosleep` call occasionally to give the other threads a chance to run.  Add the call outside the mutex pair (e.g. after the unlock).  Thread 1 is monopolizing things.

You may also want to consider restructuring and splitting up the critical [requires locking] vs non-critical work:

```
while (more) {
    lock ...
        do critical stuff ...
    unlock ...
    nanosleep ...
    do non-critical stuff
}
```

Comment: Where would I place this `nanosleep` within my code?

Comment: After the lock has been released but prior to reobtaining it. Putting the first thread to sleep will allow time for the second thread to acquire the lock etc.