# Creating a real time linux threads from bash and linux scheduling

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am new to linux kernel development. I was trying to learn thread creation and synchronization. My end goal is to create two threads and the two threads use a shared resource guarded by a semaphore.

The code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<semaphore.h>

sem_t sema_obj;

pthread_t tid[2];

int shared_val = 0;

void* doSomeThing(void *arg)
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("\n going to wait %x\n",(unsigned int)id);
    sem_wait(&sema_obj);
    shared_val++;
    sleep(1);
    printf("\n %d The value of shared_val is %d in thread %x \n",(int)i, shared_val, (unsigned int)id);
    sem_post(&sema_obj);
    printf("\n gave up sem %x\n",(unsigned int)id);
    }

    for(i=0; i<(0xFFFFFFFF);i++);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int err;
    sem_init(&sema_obj, 0, 1);
    while(i < 2)
    {
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    struct sched_param param;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO);
    param.sched_priority = 50;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param);
    //sched_setscheduler(current, SCHED_FIFO, &param);
        err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), &attr, &doSomeThing, NULL);
    //err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        else
            printf("\n Thread created successfully 0x%X \n",(unsigned int)tid[i]);

        i++;
    }
    enter code here
    sleep(60);
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it with

```
gcc -o threads_op -pthread -lrt threads.c
```

After I run the code I see:

```
 Thread created successfully 0xB75CBB40 

 going to wait b75cbb40

 Thread created successfully 0xB6DCAB40 

 going to wait b6dcab40

 0 The value of shared_val is 1 in thread b75cbb40 

 gave up sem b75cbb40

 going to wait b75cbb40

 1 The value of shared_val is 2 in thread b75cbb40 

 gave up sem b75cbb40

 going to wait b75cbb40

 2 The value of shared_val is 3 in thread b75cbb40 

 gave up sem b75cbb40

 going to wait b75cbb40

 3 The value of shared_val is 4 in thread b75cbb40 

 gave up sem b75cbb40

 going to wait b75cbb40

 4 The value of shared_val is 5 in thread b75cbb40 

 gave up sem b75cbb40

 0 The value of shared_val is 6 in thread b6dcab40 

 gave up sem b6dcab40

 going to wait b6dcab40

 1 The value of shared_val is 7 in thread b6dcab40 

 gave up sem b6dcab40

 going to wait b6dcab40

 2 The value of shared_val is 8 in thread b6dcab40 

 gave up sem b6dcab40

 going to wait b6dcab40

 3 The value of shared_val is 9 in thread b6dcab40 

 gave up sem b6dcab40

 going to wait b6dcab40

 4 The value of shared_val is 10 in thread b6dcab40 

 gave up sem b6dcab40
```

The RTPRIO is '-' for this process,
S  1000  4551  4338      - 00:00:00 threads_op

Had the following questions,

1) Why is the thread not real time and taking the priority I am setting ?

2) Why is the semaphore not getting locked alternately by the two threads and update the share variable ? The two threads have same priority.

If you know a step by step hands on tutorial to understand linux kernel topics, please share.

Comment: Why there is a reference to Bash?

Comment: You should not use sleep for realtime applications since it is only a minimum time guarantee, i.e. your thread is going to wait at least 1s , and then you will have your systems time granularity on top of that.

Comment: The wake-up for sleep will be more accurate for a real-time thread, actually.
But sleep() only has second granularity.

Answer (score 4):

A few things.

First, I hate to be a nit about things, but you're not doing linux *kernel* development.  You're writing a multithreaded *application* that runs on linux.  Thus, the `linux-kernel` tag is inappropriate.  Kernel development is about writing code that is built into the kernel, such as schedulers, device drivers, filesystem drivers, etc.

You've got a sleep *inside* your critical section (e.g. between `sem_wait` and `sem_post`).  You're experiencing "thread starvation".  See my answer here:  [Thread Synchronization C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620300/thread-synchronization-c/33620345#33620345)

Since you're using pthreads, you'd probably be better off with `pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock`.

You're also using `printf`s.  They disrupt the timing, even for debug.

You're trying to do SCHED_FIFO but not checking the return code.  Only root can set some RT schedulers and/or high[er] priorities.  Likewise, for scheduling priority.

Wow! Priority 50 for SCHED_FIFO?  If you actually got it, anything higher than 11 will schedule you at a higher priority than some internal kernel threads.  You would probably lock up the system solid. [*]

At the stage you're at, before you go "all in" [with RT scheduler, etc.], work with the normal scheduler at standard priority.  You'll be amazed at how well it will perform.  Debug your thread synchronization code/logic first before cranking up the voltage.

In reality, for a smooth highly responsive RT app that is deterministic with low latency, I think you'll need a bit more planning about *how* you'll synchronize, what queues between threads, types of locking (e.g. RCU, trylocks, timeouts on lock attempts, etc.)  How many threads will you need?  What will each one do?  Do you have pseudocode for each?  What type of thread environment (e.g. consumer/producer, master/slave/worker).  Are your threads going to do "work stealing"?  Etc, etc, etc.  Will you use IPC messaging, shared memory?  How much data?  What bandwidth for the data between threads?

[*] The reason I know this is that I was a developer on a realtime system that had 50 threads, 8 cores, and constant interaction with multiple device drivers and FPGAs and massive amounts of DMA [so much so, we had to measure it with a PCIe bus analyzer to be sure the bus had enough bandwidth].  It's now a shipping product.

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer the questions:

1) How do you know the thread is not real-time? A real-time process is different from a real-time thread. If you run this program with sudo or as root, it should get real-time priority.

2) Semaphores are not guaranteed to be fair. if you want the other thread to have a chance of incrementing the value, you have to move the sleep() call to outside the critical section with the semaphore. Posting (releasing) a semaphore does not necessarily cause a re-schedule, and thus it's totally possible for the releasing thread to immediately loop back and wait (acquire) the semaphore again.